# Problem - how to find λ?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eulers-method

Guys I need some help with this problem, I tried a thousand times but I couldn't find a realistic answer.

Solve numerically:

x'=-λ.x.y

Where:
n=x+y=500;
x0= 499 (initial condition);
with x=people who ‘do not know’ and y=people who ‘know’;
n=total number of people;

Find λ.

λ is the ‘rate of propagation of the rumor’; 
λ is a constant;
The time scale is not important.

Thanks!!

Comment: is this a differential equation?

Comment: This is lambda calculus, no?

Comment: Yes it is a differential equation.

Comment: Yes, I have to figure out the lambda.

Comment: There is an input missing on some final condition. -- See "logistic equation" for $x'=λ·x·(500-x)$. And if you have to find a rate, then the time scale is important, as that factors into the rate.

Comment: Just those information are given on the problem and I have to assume a time scale.

Comment: Or if the time scale really is not important, then you can set $λ=1$, as $x(t)=500·u(λt)$ leads to $u'=-u(1-u)$ as the (parameter-) reduced equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will take an infinite time for $x(t)$ to go down to zero, so you can introduce a time scale by assuming a "half-life" $\tau$ satisfying $x(\tau)=250$

Then the problem can be solved analytically ...

$$-\lambda \int _0^\tau dt = \int_{499}^{250}\frac{dx}{x(500-x)}
$$
You end up with $$  \lambda \tau = \frac{ln(499)}{500}  $$

Answer (score 0):

Eliminating $y$ leads to the ODE
$$
x'=-λ·x·(500-x).
$$
Parametrizing the function as $x(t)=500·u(500λ·t)$ gives the (time-reversed) logistic equation
$$
u'(t)=-u(t)·(1-u(t)),\;u(0)=\frac{499}{500}
$$
which can now be solved numerically.

---

As a Bernoulli equation, one would rather parametrize $x(t)=500/u(500λ·t)$ leading to the linear equation
$$
u'(t)=u(t)-1,\; u(0)=\frac{500}{499}.
$$